# Vertical centering a navigation menu next to an image (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-float

Well, im learning how to design with CSS and im having troubles with my CSS coding. I wanna insert and image (logo) and a navigation menu on the bottom-right part.

This is what i've made:

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <img src="imagenes/origen.png">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class = "limpiar"></div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 1% 16%;
}

.limpiar {
    clear: both;
}

body img {
    width: 100%
}

body header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

body header img {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

body header nav {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
}

li{
    margin-right: 3%;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

But i cant get the vertical and horizontal allign part! Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Bottom right part of where.(the page, the header)?

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad. I want the navigation menu on the bottom right part of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I removed a float float the "li" element.
and added "text-align: right" on "nav" element. Will advise to reduce the use of floats. I hope this helps

```css
html {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 1% 16%;
}

.limpiar {
    clear: both;
}

body img {
    width: 100%
}
body header  {
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

body header > div {
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end; 
}

body header img {
    width: 20%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

body header nav {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: right;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
    margin-right: 3%;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div>
          <img src="imagenes/origen.png">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                  <li>/</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
                  <li>/</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class = "limpiar"></div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Ok, i will try to use less floats. Do you know how to vertical allign the text? Thanks!

Comment: updated my code. is that what you meant by vertically aligning them?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you did, because the code is the same as before. But what i meant is to move the navigation menu to the bottom of the header.

Comment: When you say bottom of header, i don't understand because the <header> tag is parallel. and the menu is on the right which there is nothing on top or under it

Comment: I mean that the navigation menu could be where It is, but at the bottom of the red box